# Delete all data from table but not the columns

Tags: php, sql

How can I delete all the data in an SQL table, but not delete the columns? I want all the column names and attributes to still be there after the data is deleted.

Comment: That was 5 fast answers.

Comment: It's called [truncate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html).

Comment: some like the easy rep points

Comment: Haha, I noticed. Thanks for the comment before though @Dagon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `tableName`;
```

From the MySQL docs:

> TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely. Logically, this is equivalent to a DELETE statement that deletes all rows, but there are practical differences under some circumstances.

You could also use `DELETE FROM tableName`, but using `TRUNCATE TABLE tableName` is better because:

> Truncate operations drop and re-create the table, which is much faster than deleting rows one by one, particularly for large tables.

Comment: Why are you quoting MySQL docs when the OP did not say it was a MySQL database?

Comment: @DanBracuk It can still help you understand what it is doing, as `TRUNCATE TABLE` does pretty much the same thing in most (if not all) SQL languages

Answer (score 6):

The syntax might vary slightly depending on your database, but you probably want something like:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE my_table_name;
```

Also, `DELETE FROM my_table_name` will also work, but generally be much slower than `TRUNCATE`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the using TRUNCATE??

```
TRUNCATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete all content of a table do:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `name`
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this syntax in your sql editor

Ex: truncate table tablename

table name: demo

truncate table demo

this will delete only data and not the columns

Answer (score 0):

> delete from tablename;

it can also work

> truncate table tablename

I didn't read the question

**EDIT** I checked for

> delete from tablename;

it is also working..am i right??downvoters can you please tell the reason

'truncate'..'truncate' is more efficient than 'delete'..

Comment: Delete will also work, but is much less efficient on large tables. I think that's why you're seeing the downvotes.

Comment: I'm voting it up because truncate does not necessarily apply to all db engines and the OP did not specify one.